# Monitor Message Waiting on AS400 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ibm-midrange

What im trying to do is monitor for message waiting on active jobs on the as400 ive had a look on Google but there's no real good examples of this im guessing because its not the simplest things of doing or even possible at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what you are trying to do? Maybe a bit of code to show us? Are you calling a CL? Calling commands directly?

Comment: basicly im trying to monitor workactjob for any MSGW using some form of vb.net

Comment: Why would you use VB.NET? A [simple CL and RPG program](https://gist.github.com/916185) can do this easier.

Comment: @MikeWills has a good suggestion but be aware that the technique of parsing a spooled file has the drawback that the formatting in the printout can and does change from release to release of the operating system.

Comment: Very true Buck. This was a 30 minute project getting it to work. I would love to make it a better solution some day.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to call the appropriate APIs directly from VB.NET but it would be far easier to call a wrapper and have VB.NET process the result set.  The APIs to use are either the [List Job (QUSLJOB) API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qusljob.htm) or the [Open List of Jobs (QGYOLJOB) API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qgyoljob.htm).  QUSLJOB is simpler, but the wrapper will need to filter out jobs which are not MSGW,  QGYOLJOB is more complex, but the wrapper can select only MSGW jobs in the initial criteria.

Comment: Note that the .NET driver in Client Access cannot make direct calls to APIs. Instead an RPG or CL wrapper would have to be written and called through a SQL stored procedure. So at that point a majority of the work is written in RPG/CL why not just finish it.

Comment: Good question!  Perhaps (guessing, as it wasn't stated) @Houlahan needs to create a GUI for this.  This line of thought reminds me to suggest that [Navigator for i](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/navigator/) does this already...